# Show a div with slideDown

Tags: jquery, delay, hidden, slidedown, slideup

I have a div I want to show and hide with a check box:

```
      <li>             
        <label for="">Fixed-term package:</label>               
        <ul>                  
          <li><input id="" type="checkbox" name="package-fixed-term" /></li>               
        </ul>                       
      </li>
      <div id="package-fixed-term-options" class="hidden">
```

my class "hidden":

```
.hidden {display: none !important;}
```

When I check my input control it won't slide down.  I can get it to work by adding .removeClass('hidden') tot he line but this is not supposed to be required (e.g. slideUp doesn't need to add back my hidden class) Adding the remove class also kills the delay and slideDown animation. The slideUp works beautifully.  Here is the function:

```
$('input[name="package-fixed-term"]').change(function(){
if ($('input[name="package-fixed-term"]:checked').val() !== undefined) {     
  $('div#package-fixed-term-options').delay(300).slideDown(500);
  return false;
  } else {
  $('div#package-fixed-term-options').delay(300).slideUp(500);
  return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `!important` that is causing this issue.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JYeq/2/

Remove it from the css, and it will work:

```
.hidden {display: none;}​
```

Comment: Perfect.  I would not have suspected that as the issue yet I didn't set up these classes so I should be more suspicious.  The toggle is a good suggestion to simplify the code.  Thanks.  Still curious why !important would mess with animations.

Comment: In addition to removing the !important from the style it can be overridden in the function if the style is in-line:

    .css('display', 'block !important')

I found a clue to this in the [documentation for .show()][1]

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to accomplish this would be using "toggle"

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="$('#myDiv').toggle();" />
<div id="myDiv" style="display: block">
Here goes the DIV
</div>
```

regards, Lupo